# How to change drawable of specific Star in RatingBar?

Tags: android, ratingbar

I want to create ratingBar like penalty bar in Football

i created my custom RatingBar by this style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/circle_grey"/>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/circle_green"/>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/circle_red"/>
```

More explain:
when user got a goal so change the star drawable by index 2 in ratingBar and if user unsuccessful change star drawabale by index 2 in ratingBar to red drawable.

[red drawable](http://findicons.com/files/icons/766/base_software/128/circle_red.png)

[green drawable](http://findicons.com/files/icons/766/base_software/128/circle_green.png)

[gray drawable](http://findicons.com/files/icons/766/base_software/128/circle_grey.png)

[my RatingBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgujv.png)

[That's what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsEQc.png)

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change the color of the rating bar based on the condition, you have to do it programatically by changing your layer-list.

say if the player has made a goal.

```
private static int GREEN = 0; // progress
private static int RED= 1; // secondary progress
private static int YELLOW= 2; // background

RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
stars.getDrawable(GREEN).setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
stars.getDrawable(RED).setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
stars.getDrawable(YELLOW).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

if player hasn't made goal then,

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
stars.getDrawable(GREEN).setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
stars.getDrawable(RED).setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
stars.getDrawable(YELLOW).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Note: Make sure you have made the order i have in the layer-list.

Comment: [This is your result](http://s7.picofile.com/file/8243359092/Untitledrate.png)
 and I was not the answer.

Comment: I wont change the color of the ratingBar just **change the drawable** of that.

Comment: to make only 2 star visible use setRating(Float value) method

Comment: I know it. Nope. _Please read the questions carefully, otherwise not answered any question (wherever)_ .

Comment: Rating bar cannot be used for that purpose. You will have to use image adapter. and for each condition you can change the color of the image based on the position of the image.